# Unable to access another class

Tags: php

My Problem is that when I run this code:

```
<?php
    require_once('classes/class.users.php');

    use Users\UserService;
    use Users\UserMapper;


    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $result = $userService->handleUserLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    }
?>
```

I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: userMapper in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\SMS\classes\class.users.php on line 8

Fatal error: Call to a member function checkLogin() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\SMS\classes\class.users.php on line 8
```

My full class source: http://pastebin.com/8nahRnrT

Comment: `public $db;` isn't static. Yet you try to access it like a static `DB::$db`

Comment: in your db class make it `public static $db;` and in the construct method make it `self::$db = new mysqli(.....`

Comment: But note, you should probably look into singleton methods

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Users\UserMapper::__construct() must be an instance of Users\DB, instance of mysqli given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\SMS\classes\class.users.php on line 145 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\SMS\classes\class.users.php on line 16

Comment: What do you mean @Darren I want the UserService class not to know about the DB Details.

Comment: @Darren could you help me out if I gave you the whole code via Pastebin?

Comment: Well it seems like you have to pass the db instance to the UserService to be able to use it.

Comment: @Darren I actually dont want to create an instance of userMapper in the UserService class, but because of the error, I have to. Can you please see my code before the instance?

Comment: @Darren http://pastebin.com/8nahRnrT

Comment: @Darren I get this error: 
Notice: Undefined variable: userMapper in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\SMS\classes\class.users.php on line 8

Fatal error: Call to a member function checkLogin() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\SMS\classes\class.users.php on line 8

Comment: Did you read the error message? It's complaining about an undefined `$userMapper` variable in some code you haven't posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ronni for helping me out.

I just deleted the DB class, and I made the instance of the mysqli class instead and passed it on to the UserMapper class. I also passed on the UserMapper class instance to the UserService class and it fixed the problem.

```
$db          = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'php123', 'sms');
$userMapper  = new UserMapper($db);
$userService = new UserService($userMapper);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$userMapper->checkLogin($username, $password) === true)
```

this line, it is being called inside you `UserService` class.

`UserMapper` has never been initiated inside `UserService` class.

Perhaps **initiate it in the constructor** and add a **attribute** for it?

Comment: It gives me another error, because I need to pass a variable through it from the DB class. (Dependency Injection)

Comment: Do it, pass it along all the way to the constructor.

Comment: Anything else I can help you with?